# LyX: citation style author, year

Tags: lyx, citations

I would like to use the citation style: author, year. Which configuration do I have to use? If I do **\usepackage[comma]{natbib}** it collides with the preferences where I can only chose between numerical and author-year. 
It does not need to be natbib, I even prefer the Standard plain style, but simply would have author,year instead of [1].

Would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Instead of "author (year)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing bibliography related has to be written to the preamble. Select natbib/plainnat and author-year in Documents -> Settings -> Bibliography. Then, right-click on inserted references and select desired citation style.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd like style authordate1, see here for sme examples: http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html